# Pandas dataset from dynamic website scraping

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

This question is related to a previous question of mine, so here I am assuming that I was able to open all the "plus sigs" from [this web page from esco](http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/f8c676de-c871-424f-9a65-77059d07910a).
Once I have expanded the plus signs under "handling and disposing of waste and hazardous materials" (which is the skills to which the above link points to) how can I move from there (expanded page) to have a dataframe with 2 columns one called "Skills" and the other "Skills codes" having on the column "Skills" the skills names and on the "Skills codes" column the code of the "parent node"? In the mock uri above, this should result in something like on the "Skills" column I should have:

- collect industrial waste
- handling waste
- manage waste
- coordinate waste management procedures
- design plant waste procedures
- develop waste management processes
- dispose food waste
- dispose of soldering waste
- handle waste rock
- manage waste treatment facility
- communicate with waste treatment facilities
- train staff on waste management

and on the "Skills codes" the skill code S6.13.0.

I tried to make this as well but failed miserably:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Replace with your actual HTML file path
file_path = '/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/esco.html'

# Read the HTML file
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')

# Initialize lists to store skills and codes
skills = []
codes = []

# Find elements containing skills and their codes
# Replace 'skill_class_name' and 'code_class_name' with the actual class names or use other selectors based on your HTML structure
for skill_element in soup.find_all('div', class_='classification_item'):
   skill_name = skill_element.get_text(strip=True)
   skills.append(skill_name)
   
   # Assuming the code is in a close relation to the skill element, you might need to adjust the method of finding it
   code_element = skill_element.find_next_sibling('div', class_='main_item')
   if code_element:
       skill_code = code_element.get_text(strip=True)
       codes.append(skill_code)
   else:
       codes.append('')  # Append an empty string or None if no code is found

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Skill': skills,
   'Code': codes
})

print(df)
```

**Notice:** I called the uri a "mock uri" because in reality I have many mores uri and have to repeat the same procedure over and over.

Answer (score 0):

I find the anchor tags (`<a>`) easier to scrape than the `div`s:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile("(.+) - (.+)")

data = []
for anchor in soup.find_all('a', class_='change_right_content'):
   skill_name = anchor.get_text(strip=True)
   if m := pattern.match(skill_name):
      data.append(m.groups())

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Code', 'Skill'])
```

You can refine the regex pattern to match `S1.0` but not `S`, etc.

`:=` is called the "walrus operator" and requires Python 3.8 or later.